# MP4/WebM Compatibility Issues

Tags: html, cross-browser, zurb-foundation, mp4, webm

I have a short custom made mp4 video that is not playing on all devices. It works on my laptop (new MacBook) but on all phones and some other desktops it does not. It's either just pulling up a still image or showing nothing at all. I haven't been able to tie it down to a browser issue b/c it does not consistently show up properly in any browser across all devices. Below is a portion of my code. I am using HTML5/Foundation 6.4.2. The site is [Here](http://hydepowerpotion.com.) The mp4 is an animation of a can spinning, so no controls are needed. Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle align-center">
    <div class="large-7 medium-9 cell">
      <video autoplay loop poster="" id="" class="bgvid">
        <source src="video/can-rotation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/can-rotation.webm" type="video/webm"> 
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @aergistal do you know if there is a workaround for the safari issue? also, the problem isn't limited to iOS devices, it's not playing on any mobile devices (android/apple/etc.).

Comment: According to [this](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/) and [this](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) it should work if it doesn't have an audio track or if you use `<video muted>`. Try and see if it resolves the issue on Android too.